# minColor and MaxColor inside colorAxis not working for HeatMaps in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to implement heat maps using HighCharts Library.

here is the link that am currently referring:
URL: https://jsfiddle.net/br0ocjf6/32/

Below is my chart definition for Heat Maps. I am unable to see the background color of each cell based on the value as i have set the minColor and maxColor in colorAxis

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
   chart:{
      "type":"heatmap",
      "spacingLeft":45,
      "spacingRight":45,
      "spacingBottom":45,
      "spacingTop":45,
      "height":500,
      "reflow":true,
      "inverted":false
   },

   colorAxis: {
        min: 0,
        minColor: '#000000',
        maxColor: '#FFFFFF'
    },

   series:[
      {
         "name":"100005",
         "data":[
            {
               "x":0,
               "y":0,
               "g":100005
            }
         ],
         "dataLabels":{
            "borderWidth":20,
            "color":"#ffffff",
            "enabled":true
         },
         "dataType":"string",
         "color":"#00c9e8"
      },
      {
         "name":"100004.07",
         "data":[
            {
               "x":1,
               "y":1,
               "g":100004.07
            }
         ],
         "dataLabels":{
            "borderWidth":20,
            "color":"#ffffff",
            "enabled":true
         },
         "dataType":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"100004.08",
         "data":[
            {
               "x":2,
               "y":1,
               "g":100004.08
            }
         ],
         "dataLabels":{
            "borderWidth":20,
            "color":"#ffffff",
            "enabled":true
         },
         "dataType":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"100004.09",
         "data":[
            {
               "x":3,
               "y":0,
               "g":100004.09
            }
         ],
         "dataLabels":{
            "borderWidth":20,
            "color":"#ffffff",
            "enabled":true
         },
         "dataType":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"100005.01",
         "data":[
            {
               "x":4,
               "y":0,
               "g":100005.01
            }
         ],
         "dataLabels":{
            "borderWidth":20,
            "color":"#ffffff",
            "enabled":true
         },
         "dataType":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"100005.02",
         "data":[
            {
               "x":5,
               "y":1,
               "g":100005.02
            }
         ],
         "dataLabels":{
            "borderWidth":20,
            "color":"#ffffff",
            "enabled":true
         },
         "dataType":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"100005.03",
         "data":[
            {
               "x":6,
               "y":1,
               "g":100005.03
            }
         ],
         "dataLabels":{
            "borderWidth":20,
            "color":"#ffffff",
            "enabled":true
         },
         "dataType":"string"
      },
      {
         "name":"100005.04",
         "data":[
            {
               "x":7,
               "y":1,
               "g":100005.04
            }
         ],
         "dataLabels":{
            "borderWidth":20,
            "color":"#ffffff",
            "enabled":true
         },
         "dataType":"string"
      }
   ],
   yAxis:[
      {
         "gridLineWidth":0,
         "opposite":false,
         "columnName":"string",
         "title":{
            "useHtml":true,
            "margin":15,
            "text":"string",
            "style":{

            }
         },
         "labels":{
            "style":{

            }
         },
         "index":0
      }
   ],
   xAxis:{
      "categories":[
         "27/01/19",
         "01/01/19",
         "25/01/19",
         "26/01/19",
         "28/01/19",
         "29/01/19",
         "30/01/19",
         "31/01/19"
      ],
      "title":{
         "y":15,
         "text":"Date"
      }
   }
});


Can anyone help me understand why am not able to view the background color as specified in colorAxis?
```

Comment: Hi @LS2, Your example seems to work correctly. Maybe I missed something, so could you explain your problem more precisely?

Comment: Can you please share a link to the working piece of code?

Comment: Screen from your jsfiddle link: https://imgshare.io/image/heatmap.14LTQ